# Member Login API

Tags: api, rest

Please excuse me because I am extremely new to ExpressionEngine, and I don't quite understand how to achieve this...

I have been searching for a RESTful API plugin, or an example on how to develop one for a few days.

I think that [this](https://expressionengine.stackexchange.com/a/12) is the closest of a piece what I am trying to do.

I would like to use the Member database table to be able to validate credentials and respond with a token or some sort.

Does anyone have an example or something that will point me in the right direction?

Again I'm sorry for the novice question, I'm just lost at where to begin.

Thank you!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found a [great blog](https://medium.com/expressionengine-cms/building-an-api-for-your-add-ons-with-expressionengine-and-the-a-team-85c1c9bc9e2c) to help me in this and was able to get it to work fairly well.

[His Github was helpful too.](https://github.com/patpohler/EE-Mission-Tracker/blob/master/system/expressionengine/third_party/mission_tracker)

Needed to follow the add-on development guide also to bring it up to date, because this one was older. Mainly it was just the addon.setup.php file

Answer (score 0):

I don't think EE has any API.

You can do this by tapping directly into the SQL database with custom code I guess to match the user password hash and if yes, give the token.

If you want an API while I didn't tested it, there is this addon I found:
https://docs.reinos.nl/webservice/